# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int' in Python

Tags: python

I keep getting the error in the title when I try to run this code. I thought that the problem was to do with the variables not being integers, but that didn't fix the problem. Here is the code:

```
shoeSize=int(input("Please enter your shoe size."))
ageOne=int(input("Please enter your age."))

if ageOne >= 18:
    print("Your membership fee is £" & shoeSize*10)
elif ageOne <= 65:
        print("Your membership fee is £" & shoeSize*5)
else:
        print ("You cannot join!")
```

Comment: `&`? Look into string interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `&` for string concatenation in e.g. Visual Basic, but it's the bitwise AND operator in Python.

The most modern (and simplest, I'd say) way to format strings is to make them "f-strings":

```
shoeSize = int(input("Please enter your shoe size."))
ageOne = int(input("Please enter your age."))

if ageOne >= 18:
    print(f"Your membership fee is £{shoeSize*10}")
elif ageOne <= 65:
    print(f"Your membership fee is £{shoeSize*5}")
else:
    print("You cannot join!")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem of wrong syntax:

```
if ageOne >= 18:
    print("Your membership fee is £" & shoeSize*10)
                                     ^

elif ageOne <= 65:
        print("Your membership fee is £" & shoeSize*5)
                                         ^
```

You can use `,` instead:

```
if ageOne >= 18:
    print("Your membership fee is £", shoeSize*10)
                                    ^

elif ageOne <= 65:
        print("Your membership fee is £", shoeSize*5)
                                        ^
```